# How to pass an empty array to a map?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, insert, stdmap

Here is my question.

```
private:
map<string,int &> days;
int daysHours[6] = {};
```

I have `private` data like this.

```
void Schedule::studentSchedule()
{
    getDays().insert(pair<string, int&>("Monday", daysHours));
    getDays().insert(pair<string, int& >("Tuesday", daysHours));
    getDays().insert(pair<string, int&>("Wednesday", daysHours));
    getDays().insert(pair<string, int& >("Thursday", daysHours));
    getDays().insert(pair<string, int&>("Friday", daysHours));

    map<string, int&>::iterator it;
    for (it = getDays().begin(); it != getDays().end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << "Day: " << it->first << "\tHours: " << it->second << endl;
    }
}
```

I this function I want to create a map with days and empty array.

When I do that I am getting an error like this.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int&>::pair(const char [7], int [6])'
 getDays().insert(pair<string,int &>("Monday",daysHours));
```

Can you help me about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [plain arrays decay to pointers of the array's type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying), not the references. Meaning `daysHours` decays to `int*` not `int&`. That was the reason for the compiler error **[See here live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/B8XZWsKoEUwS5YCH)**. Therefore you need to provide map's key as an `int*`.:

```
std::map<string, int*> days;
//              ^^^^
```

---

However, you can use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of plain arrays.

```
#include <map>
#include <array>


using Array = std::array<int, 6>;  // convenience type
std::map<std::string, Array> days;
Array daysHours{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

days.emplace("Monday", daysHours);  // constrcut in place
//... rest
```

---

As a side note, do not practice with “`using namespace std;`. See the following post for more info:
[Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @JeJo's answer, if you really want to use static arrays, then you'd need to declare their fixed size beforehand.
A good alternative to this is to use `vector` that are essentially dynamic arrays.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"Using static arrays\n";
    map<string,int (*)[6]> days;
    int daysHours[6] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    days.insert(pair<string,int (*)[6]>("Monday",&daysHours));
    days.insert(pair<string,int (*)[6] >("Tuesday",&daysHours));
    days.insert(pair<string,int (*)[6]>("Wednesday",&daysHours));
    days.insert(pair<string,int (*)[6] >("Thursday",&daysHours));
    days.insert(pair<string,int (*)[6]>("Friday",&daysHours));
    map<string,int (*)[6]>::iterator it;
    for(it=days.begin();it!=days.end();++it)
    {
        cout<<"Day: "<<it->first<<"\tHours: ";
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
            cout<<*(*(it->second)+i)<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Alternative solution: Use vectors(dynamic arrays)\n";
    map<string,vector<int>> days2;
    vector<int> daysHours2{0,1,2};
    days2.insert(pair<string,vector<int>>("Monday",daysHours2));
    days2.insert(pair<string,vector<int> >("Tuesday",daysHours2));
    days2.insert(pair<string,vector<int>>("Wednesday",daysHours2));
    days2.insert(pair<string,vector<int> >("Thursday",daysHours2));
    days2.insert(pair<string,vector<int>>("Friday",daysHours2));
    map<string,vector<int>>::iterator it2;
    for(it2=days2.begin();it2!=days2.end();++it2)
    {
        cout<<"Day: "<<it2->first<<"\tHours: ";
        for(auto i:it2->second){
            cout<<i<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Using static arrays
Day: Friday     Hours: 0 1 2 3 4 5 
Day: Monday     Hours: 0 1 2 3 4 5 
Day: Thursday   Hours: 0 1 2 3 4 5 
Day: Tuesday    Hours: 0 1 2 3 4 5 
Day: Wednesday  Hours: 0 1 2 3 4 5 
Alternative solution: Use vectors(dynamic arrays)
Day: Friday     Hours: 0 1 2 
Day: Monday     Hours: 0 1 2 
Day: Thursday   Hours: 0 1 2 
Day: Tuesday    Hours: 0 1 2 
Day: Wednesday  Hours: 0 1 2
```